# Adjust width based on parent and add elipsis w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to adjust the width of an element based on parent's width and add an ellipsis at the end. Here's what I've got. Looks straight forward but I can't seem to be able to add ellipsis. What did I miss?

```
<style>
.myClass{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

$(".myClass").each(function() {
    var str = $(this);
    var par = str.parent().width();
    var newWidth = par - 20; // to allow room for ellipsis
    str.width(newWidth);
    str.append("...");
});


<div style="width: 100px">
    <span class="myClass">My long text string here. Even longer goes on and on.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: new is not a good name to use for a var

Comment: `"width" 100px"` is malformed, should be `"width: 100px".  Not the issue you're asking about though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to make a few changes.  The biggest is that `display:hidden` means that the `...` you add will be clipped off.  You need to append that `...` to the parent element.  Also, I changed the `span` to `display:inline-block;` so that `display:hidden` would work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/u6XfD/

Note: This is not a great idea since as you can see in that fiddle, it may cut characters off in the middle.

Comment: Agreed. What is the better way to doing it on a client side? I assume I need to count chars and and the same time measure the width?

Comment: I truthfully haven't really seen it done well horizontally.  I would guess it would have to be like you said, character count and width, but it's probably too much computationally that it would affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

instead of .append() try `str.text(str.text()+"&hellip;");`

Comment: The text is still going to get clipped off by his `display: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
    var str = $(this);
    var par = str.parent().width();
    var newer = par - 20; // to allow room for ellipsis
    str.width(newer);
    $("...").appendTo(str);
});
```